# Margin CSS not taking affect to checkbox element

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I'm a little confused to why the `margin` `CSS` I am applying to my `checkbox` element isn't working. Here is an example of my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="panel">
         <input id="bodytype-checkbox" class="float-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
         <label for="bodytype-checkbox" class="label-checkbox">Bodytype</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.float-checkbox{
    float:left;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LvhCh/38/

Comment: @jRulle, where you saw bootstrap here? Message to people who walk to review and accept editions randomly, stop doing that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like bootstrap.css is a little more specific when styling checkboxes.

```
input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {
  margin: 4px 0 0;
  margin-top: 1px \9;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

and it's overriding yours.

Comment: So you could adjust your class with `input[type=checkbox].float-checkbox` to override theirs.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
input.float-checkbox{
    float:left;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default the checkbox is using bootstraps.css margin. To override this use a more specific css selector. Use the below css

```
input[type=checkbox].float-checkbox{
  float:left;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Out the margin on the label... CSS can act a little funny on checkboxes and other form elements.

```
label { margin-left: 10px; }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/LvhCh/41/)**

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `input` in the start of class
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LvhCh/40/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is that your CSS is overwritten by the bootstrap css. This means you have to overrule their CSS. You can do this in multiple ways.

1) Add the element type in front of your CSS: `input.float-checkbox`

2) Add another class in front of your CSS: `.panel .float-checkbox`